# Responsive manually cropped images rendered in twig template

Tags: 8, media, theming

I have created **responsive image style** and connected it to 3 different image styles(640x400, 800x400, 1920x500).

I have added an image field into a content type with custom crop format assigned(field's display form) and responsive image as the display format.

If I use drupal's default theme flow all is printed well. However, my goal is to print this out through twig. Any idea on how to succeed on this?

Comment: Your question in wrong :) When it come down to it all markup is printed by Twig (through various templates). You should state what it is that you actually want to achieve, as I'm sure the goal itself is not to create twig templates...

Comment: ... and the "drupal's default theme flow" is a result of the render array, that goes into theming, not the other way around. So you probably need to tackle this in field formatter, view or preprocess hooks.

Comment: Sorry for the phrasing. Drupal is using twig indeed :-) I have overwritten the Content Type's template with my own twig. I would like to be able to render the image element in the same way. Is there an easy way to do it? or should I re-implement responsive image's preprocess process. I am a bit lost...